# Unable to see saved passwords on Chrome for Mac v 71.0.3578.98

Tags: macos, google-chrome, passwords

I used to be able to see my passwords in Chrome like this:

[image]

But this does not work anymore in my current version of Chrome (71.0.3578.98 for Mac):

[image]

For some reason:

- All my saved passwords have moved under the "Never saved" section (but I have confirmed that these passwords are still saved and auto-filled when I go to these domains)
- The buttons to show the password (and other options) don't exist anymore.

How can I get back the button to see my saved passwords? If that's not possible, how can I export them? Thanks!

Comment: Beyond the one IP address that's listed in both pics, I'm not sure that you can say all of your saved passwords have moved to the Never Save section.  You should check that your passwords are still stored online (click the passwords.google.com link in the 2nd pic).  Then, sign out of Chrome, sign back in, and re-sync from your online saved profile.  If that doesn't repeat, but throw away your Chrome profile folder on your Mac in between signing out and in.

Comment: Thansk @jimtut . About your first comment, I have 50+ passwords in the "Never Saved" section, which seems a plausible number, and they all seem to work. About the second comment, I have never been signed in to Chrome. These passwords are only in my local machine, and I would prefer to keep it this way.

Comment: What do you see if you click that link to View and Manage Passwords in your Google acct?  If you're not signed into Chrome, I would expect that to say something different.  Also, have you looked in your Mac Keychain?  There's a chance Chrome is saving them there.

Comment: There's one more thing you can try, *if* you're very comfortable in the Terminal and with SQL.  I had to recover passwords from a corrupted Chrome profile once, and I was able to do with SQL (Chrome uses a database file to store them), but it's not easy, requires some hunting around (SQL "select"), reformatting data maybe in a good text editor, and copying the data to a new Chrome profile (SQL "insert").  If the other stuff didn't help you find them and you can handle the SQL, let me know and I'll write up a full answer later on Friday.